# telegram bot на python падает через некоторое время

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Создал бота на python, мой первый опыт. И всё вроде хорошо, но через несколько часов он просто падает, например если на ночь его оставить на дедике, то к утру я получу трэйсбэк. При чем очень длинный, и я даже не смог разобраться из-за чего он. Не нашел подобных проблем на форумах.

Последнее сообщение в трэйсбеке:
**requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))**

*Если нужен полный трэйсбек, выгрузил его сюда:* https://disk.yandex.ru/d/w1n04oMdOYasAQ?w=1

Я пытался вчитываться в сообщение об ошибке, но не нашёл ни одного модуля который писал сам.

Comment: Добавьте трассу стека в вопрос, вопрос должен быть самодостаточным :)

Comment: Бот загружен на pythonanywhere?

Comment: у вас `bot.polling()` завернут в try:except?

Comment: бота загружал на личный выделенный сервер, загуглил pythonanywhere, думаю лучше выгружу туда, спасибо))
насчет bot.polling(), он без try:except, но кажется проблема все таки в хосте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по ошибке, просто перенесите бота на новый сервер.
Почему сервер дисконектит - тут лучше спросить у вашего хоста либо админа.